# I am using Xamarin Shell but I would also like to open pages without the Shell sometimes. How can I do that?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am using shell and I would like to go to this page:

```
public AppManagementPage(
        IMainThread mainThread,
        IAnalyticsService analyticsService,
        AppManagementPageViewModel appManagementPageViewModel) : base(appManagementPageViewModel, analyticsService, mainThread)
    {
```

Normally I have been defining a route in the usual way and just using this command.

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("App/AppManagementPage", typeof(AppManagementPage));
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("App/AppManagementPage", true);
```

However as I need DI to populate all the parameters I am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection I first need to get a reference page like this:

```
var myAppManagementPage = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppManagementPage>();
```

then I need to go open this new page: myAppManagementPage

Can you help explain / suggest how I can navigate to myAppManagementPage without using Shell?

Comment: I am not familiar with how you are using DependencyInjection  in Xamarin, but could you clarify why you cannot use shell method? is your page not instantiated yet ? it is not in yout AppShell.xaml ?

Comment: I will add in the constructor of my page as an example.

Comment: Hi, whether the `AppManagementPage` is the root page of application?